# How many days does it take for Google Webmaster Tools to refresh after a DNS error?

Tags: web-hosting, google-search-console, dns

Yesterday I saw a problem in Google Webmaster Tools - it's saying that "Googlebot can not crawl your site because of DNS errors."

Please view this image & error date:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auP1.png]

Then I immediately fixed the problems. Now I can see in the graph from two days there is not a DNS problem, but it's still showing a DNS error.

I am wondering how many days does it take Google to to refresh this DNS graph in order to remove the error?

Important Links: http://ansoftsys.com/sitemap.xml and http://ansoftsys.com/robots.txt.

Comment: I believe there is a 2 day lag, can someone confirm this?

Comment: not sure what policy you are violating. Were you clicking on ur own ads a little too many times?

Comment: @Prasad  I have not get Adsense account yet. I given my website(http://www.ansoftsys.com/) to Google adsense for review.   Do you think i will get adsense for my website. Please give me any suggestions regarding my website

Comment: @Prasad Prasad. Yaar please help karo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They crawl when they get around to the Domain, I've seen it anywhere from 2 days to 1 week.

You can use an XML [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) to give a hint about how often it should be crawled, but it's only a hint not a command, and requesting specific days is not possible.

You might even be recrawled now as you're reading this, it's best to wait a while, but it does get back. I had a DNS error with my setup and it took 4 days for them to get back with  set to always. (I think that's why it took so long because they can't crawl it every second and store it)

If they don't crawl for a long period (e.g. a month) I suggest posting a bug report, I've seen people talking about GoogleBot not crawling for over a month, when it should have been crawled.

Comment: @yeah i am waiting for it. it became 4 days. But still the same error